# How to get JS variable from Google Script?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script

Hello guys im new on Google Script,
im making an app that read the input from the box,
and then send it to the mysql.

I have this:

-

Codigo.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('getIp');
}

var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORT/DB", "USER", "PW");
 // perform the query
var SQLstatement = connection.createStatement();
var result = SQLstatement.executeQuery("Insert Into IPS Values(IPFromPrompt,0)");
```

Look at "IPFromPrompt" there is where i want IP from the following code

GetIp.html

```
<div>
<p>Click the button and enter your IP Addess.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="AddIP"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var IP = prompt("Please enter your IP Address", "");

    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("AddIP").innerHTML =
        "Added " + IP + "to our database";
    }
}
</script>
</div>
```

Do you know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got multiple problems here.  You need a `google.script.run` call to trigger the `.gs` code from the HTML.  Your `myFunction()` function needs to have `google.script.run`.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var IP = prompt("Please enter your IP Address", "");
    var theUserInput = To Do . . .Get user input;

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .processInput(theUserInput)

  }

  function onSuccess(argIP) {
    if (person != null) {
      document.getElementById("AddIP").innerHTML =
        "Added " + argIP + "to our database";
    }
  };
</script>
```

### Codigo.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('getIp');
}

function processInput(argGetInput) {
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORT/DB", "USER", "PW");
  // perform the query
  var SQLstatement = connection.createStatement();
  var result = SQLstatement.executeQuery("Insert Into IPS Values(IPFromPrompt,0)");

  return result;
};
```